# Looking for an English word or expression for not having a real boss in charge

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms, politics

There is a Hungarian word *fejetlenség*, literally, having no head, in the state of having no head, meaning a situation where a state or an organisation is an unruly mess.

Is there an English expression for this?

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/disorganization

gives many synonyms

but I did not find one that uses this way of expression

a figurative one

is there one?

UPDATE: unruly mess itself might be close, as

http://www.finedictionary.com/unruly.html

says unruly is "unwilling to submit authority", in my words: disobedience

but what I want to emphasize is that there is no authority, not that people rebel against it

Comment: That's one of the many meanings of _free_. In specific contexts, _unruly_ itself has that sense, with transparent morphology.

Comment: The English idiom 'running around like a headless chicken' describes the chaos of headlessness. It would be difficult to apply to the case of having no boss.

Comment: @grateful so headlessness is a word in English, good. Only it is not used in the figurative meaning I describe above, only literally for an animal, I guess.

Comment: Yes, in the sense of not having a head (face, scull, etc.). For a boss it would be 'leaderless'.

Comment: You could describe the situation as "the blind leading the blind".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider ***rudderless*** *to **describe the organisation** when no (real) boss is present*.

> **[rudderless](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rudderless)** (adjective)
>   (of an organization) without anyone in control and therefore unable to take decisions

You should check ***unaccountable*** *from the perspective of the **staff** when no (real) boss is present*.

> [***unaccountable***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unaccountable):
>
> : not required to explain actions or decisions
>
> : not required to be responsible for something

Comment: that is about a leader who abuses his power. I want to express that a leader is weak and lets the organisation fall apart.

Comment: I have edited the answer to describe the organisation as well (*rudderless*). The term *unaccountable* is to describe the staff; clarified this point as well.

Comment: I think rudderless is a good choice, to describe the country or organisation.

Comment: @alwayslearning thanks, that contains the meaning I sought.

Answer (score 3):

Consider

> [HEADLESS](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/headless)

From Webster

> 1. without a head
> 2. without a leader

or even simply

> Leaderless

Although it does not show as an individual entry in the dictionary, its' the most common.

Compare leaderless with headless and rudderless, the later does not even register in Ngram.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"[Acephalous](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acephalous)" is a rare word, but it's legitimate English - basically a Greek calque off the word "headless."